# Make sheets scripted button visible in mobile

Tags: google-apps-script, mobile

So I created a google spreadsheet and on it I inserted a couple of graphics with script functions associated to them (so my sheet has a bound script to it). Those functions will combine some of the information contained on cells in my sheet and format them into another cell.
So everything is working fine on my desktop PC. I can access my sheet, click on the buttons and have the functionality running. But when I access the sheet through my mobile phone (Nexus 5) I cannot see the buttons I created on the sheet. I don't have any clue about what can be causing this.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: That's not an Apps Script issue, but the mobile app you're using to open the spreadsheet. Open it in a browser and request the desktop version should do it. Anyway, since this is not about programming this question is not a good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing Google Apps Script Functions from Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373826/executing-google-apps-script-functions-from-mobile-app)