# Display message from onEdit() in "Google Sheets" Android app

Tags: mobile, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, menu

I use `onEdit()` in Google Sheets to control users' activities. Google Sheets must work as on Desktop as on mobile device with Android. Everything works, but I can't to show any message at all on mobile device. `Browser.msgBox()` - don't work. [Dialogs and Sidebars in G Suite Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs), example "Custom dialogs" and "Custom sidebars" work under Windows but don't work on mobile device too.

Help please, somebody!!!

As a last resort, how in script `onEdit()` to determine where Google Sheets was opened: on desktop or on mobile device?

Comment: If you want a mobile-inclusive solution, Avoid all desktop based solutions completely: msgBox, sidebars, dialogs and stuff. Only use mobile compatible solutions like `onEdit()`, custom functions,setNote() or setValue() as error, datavalidation drop downs, etc.

Comment: A  partial workaround way : You can make a `google.script.run(<function to setCache/property>)` from the sidebar to check whether the side bar is open> thus checking whether the edit is on desktop/mobile.

Comment: Thank for quick answer. I did assume it, but hope dies last...   Interesting tip, thank. But I am beginner in google script. Can you write example, please.

Comment: Really is it simplest metod to determine platform?

Comment: The workaround is to answer your last question(figure out whether onEdit is from mobile/desktop) and it's not really a answer. If there's a sidebar, it'll call server(using google.script.run). Mobiles won't load html and thus there is no server call. But, I don't think it's worth pursuing and I'm not gonna post that as a answer. A better way is just to avoid all desktop stuff. Or You can also develop separate a  Android add-on(which is in developer preview for 5+ years: So, I don't recommend that either). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373826

Comment: I understanded. Thank you very march.