# Is there any limitation using google apps script for google sheets in chrome OS (chromebook)?

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I would like to create a google sheet with some automation using google apps script (e.g. checking text, displaying pop-up, changing tab...), with these functionnalities available on a small & cheap device such as tablet or small computer (chromebook...).

I created the script and it works well on a desktop computer, but when I tried on an android tablet I saw that the functionnality is really limited. As described in a some other posts (e.g. [How to get google sheets script working on mobile app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846603/how-to-get-google-sheets-script-working-on-mobile-app) and [Display message from onEdit() in "Google Sheets" Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741842/display-message-from-onedit-in-google-sheets-android-app)), I realized that it is quite complicated to make things work on such a device.

My question is: will my problems be solved if I buy a chromebook instead of an android tablet ?
I never had one so I do not know if google apps script works the same on a chromebook as on a desktop computer.

If not, what is the simplest solution ?

Comment: If you don't use html/alerts, `onEdit` will work well within mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no limitation.  My main laptop is a cheap Chromebook and I do Apps Script all day.

Comment: Thanks ! I will invest in a chromebook then.