# Check if a sheet with name=week number exists when opening sheet on Android

Tags: android, google-apps-script, mobile, google-sheets

I'd like to trigger a check if a sheet with "name = current week number" exists when I open my Google spreadsheet on Android and if not - create such sheet by duplicating first sheet and giving it a "name = current week number". 
In the past I couldn't get "on Open()" trigger to work on mobile Sheets even with created "on Open(e)" simple trigger.

As far as I understand, first thing I need is to get "var = current week number". I've looked through some solutions on SO but wasn't able to make something out of them.

Here's the link to the test sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ffFy7aCkaInRbp9w5_WUoB2VkV8nZoSEG2z32WelEqM/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing Google Apps Script Functions from Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373826/executing-google-apps-script-functions-from-mobile-app)

Answer (score 2):

`onOpen` triggers don't fire on mobile.

The best way for you is a time-based trigger which fires every week.