# Run a google script when user clicks on a particular link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have around 500+ rows  of data in a 1 column in spreadsheet with a particular link. Whenever a user clicks on a link an Appscript script should run..I have been using buttons to assign script..But for 500+ rows I can't create buttons and assign script individually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [button click is only working on Windows & not working on Android mobile sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840757/button-click-is-only-working-on-windows-not-working-on-android-mobile-sheet)

Comment: Is the script to run always the same? I am not quiet sure either you want to run the script on button click or on link click? In the latter case you can deploy the script as a  a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and paste its URL as the link to be clicked.

Comment: You can use just one button perhaps on the sidebar and just let that button call a script that determines what the current row is and then run the script based on active row.

Comment: Thank you Cooper and zinganotschka for your valuable comments.The issue is resolved