# Assigned Script to a Multiple Drawings Does Not Run on Phone Sheets App

Tags: button, google-apps-script, mobile, google-sheets, drawing

I hope you can help me with this. I have assigned a script to multiple drawings (as buttons) in Google Sheets and is running perfectly on PC. When I try it on my phone, the script does not run, but rather gives an option to edit. What should I do, please?

Comment: @Rubén thank you for the answer but unfortunately it does not work for me as I have multiple buttons with multiple scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Sheets mobile apps doesn't support using drawings as buttons (assign a  Google Apps Script function).

Regarding what you should do, you should look for other ways to call your functions from a mobile apps like using a edit trigger.

Related

- [button click is only working on Windows & not working on Android mobile sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840757/button-click-is-only-working-on-windows-not-working-on-android-mobile-sheet)