# How to show a confirmation message while selecting a value of a dropdown list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am selecting values from two dropdown lists in Google Sheets. In cell A4 I select subject code like IT101, Math301, PHY105 and son on. And in cell B4 there are 'No Class, Start 1-Period and Start 2-Period' in the dropdown list.

What I want is, in A4 I will select my subject code and then when I will select any item from the dropdown list in B4 (B4 cell value is linked with onEdit Trigger), I want to see a confirmation message like "Confirm your subject..." If I press OK, it will execute the functions below like refreshSheet() and onePeriod(). But if I cancel it, it will do nothing. In this code, the issues is, it is showing message but the code is executed automatically no matter whether I am pressing Ok or Cancel button. Please advise.

```
function onEdit(e){  
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B4' && e.range.getValue() === "Start 1-Period") { 
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("Confirm Your Subject Details!!", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (button == ui.Button.OK){
      refreshSheet();
      onePeriod();
    }
  }  
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B4' && e.range.getValue() === "Start 2-Period") {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("Confirm Your Subject Details!!", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (button == ui.Button.OK){
      refreshSheet();
      onePeriod();
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to implement an additional `if` statement running the rest of the code only if `Button.OK` was clicked:

```js
    var button = ui.alert("Confirm Your Subject!!", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);    
    if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
      refreshSheet();
      onePeriod();
    }
```

Comment: Still the same result. Please check my revised code at the original post.

Comment: Excuse me, I just saw that I skipped the variable declaration - you need it for the `if` statement.

Comment: It is working in Computer browser but not in Google Sheets App.

Comment: What do you mean? Try: `if (ui.alert("Confirm Your Subject Details!!", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL) == ui.Button.OK){
      ui.alert("You clicked ok");
      refreshSheet();
      onePeriod();
    } else{
      ui.alert("You clicked cancel");
    }` If you can see the alerts but your functions do not run correctly, then the problem must be inside those functions.

Comment: By `Google Sheets App` do you mean the mobile App on your phone?

Comment: Yes, mobile app

Comment: Oh, I see. Does `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` work for you on android at all?

Comment: No, it does not work. People often wants to work from android app. That's the problem. Is there any other solution that works both in computer and mobile.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373826/executing-google-apps-script-functions-from-mobile-app), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840757/button-click-is-only-working-on-windows-not-working-on-android-mobile-sheet/57842475#57842475) and [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/add-a-script-trigger-to-google-sheet-that-will-work-in-android-mobile-app). Unfortunately the approach above is only for use on computers, not mobile phones.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I realised that it does not at mobile apps.