# Google script won't run on mobile

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile

I have made a spreadsheet in Google Sheets containing Youtube URLs.

I also made the following script:

```
function shuffleSheet() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("A4:D17");

// Randomizes the range
range.randomize();
}
```

I add a trigger to the sheet that when I open the file the script runs. So the rows get shuffled each time I open the sheet.

This is working on a Desktop PC but it isn't working on my Android phone when I open the sheet with the Google Sheets app.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there soms way I could get this working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing Google Apps Script Functions from Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373826/executing-google-apps-script-functions-from-mobile-app)

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+%5Bmobile%5D+user%3A8404453)

Answer (score -1):

Reading online.. it appears that since the mobile version is not a full version of Google Sheet **it's not possible to run custom code** on the mobile app (including android) because is not supported.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33587638)