# How to test Google Workspace add-on on mobile (Android/iOS) in Google Sheets app?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a simple Google Workspace add-on that I'm building for myself to use with Google Sheets.

It works on desktop. But if open the Sheets app on my Android phone I can't access it.

My question: how I start/access/install the *test deployment* version of my app on mobile? Do I need to publish it to be able to access it on my phone?

Comment: Are you encountering any error/s when accessing it to your Android phone?

Comment: No error, the add-on's functionality cannot be accessed, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no add-on that currently works with the mobile Google sheets app.

However, some script functionalities work: [Executing Google Apps Script Functions from Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373826)

Comment: Shoot, I was under the impression that this does work. Only seem to work with Gmail based on what the official docs say: **Extend desktop and mobile clients for Gmail: If a Google Workspace Add-on extends Gmail, you can use it in both the desktop and mobile versions of Gmail. If you build a Google Workspace Add-on that extends Gmail, you don't need to design a separate mobile version of the add-on. The same interface is used everywhere.**

Comment: @KohányiRóbert Yeah... The official docs seems to be purposely misleading. That quote was actually added later, somewhere inconspicuous  in the documentation, after backlash.

Comment: Yeah, talk about a pseudo-cross-platform UI library. It would be freakin' awesome if this Card business would be truly cross-platform.

Comment: Has this changed since the Android Sheets app now has an add-ons menu which takes you to play store?

Comment: @jazzwhistle Not that I know of. It always had a addons menu which took you to play store. Few years back it even had a small collection of addons. Now, I don't think there's any. Have you successfully installed any?

Comment: No, the ones listed don't seem to be add-ons at all... but I remember how Calendar Add-ons in the browser were initially restricted to Zoom and other big players before they opened it up, and was hoping mobile Sheets add-ons might follow the same path.