# Getting Spreadsheet.Ui features to work on Android app

Tags: android, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, modal-dialog

I have a Google Sheet on which I'm using a number of modal dialogs, using the SpreadsheetApp.Ui object, like this:

```
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("You must select an inquiry to create an estimate.",ui.ButtonSet.OK);
```

It works great on desktop in Chrome; on the Android Sheets app it does nothing. I've looked around and only found some old posts suggesting this is not possible to do. Have things changed? Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: AFAIK, Nothing has changed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207643/

Comment: @TheMaster  Yet another thing from Google that's almost really great but then isn't quite. I guess it is free though.

Comment: @TheMaster By the way your solution on the other thread you suggested was good. That's basically how I've been handling things. The thing is sometimes I want to tell the user that they're doing something wrong in a dialog box. I guess my alternative is just a display that message on the sheet with a checkbox to clear it. another user suggested creating dropdown lists using data validation to call functions, and I've been doing that also since I don't really like custom menus (and they don't work on mobile).